# How do you unit test plugins?

Tags: setup, tests

I have Codeception running on my local install without errors, but it's not yet actually doing anything. I am building several plugins and I can't figure out how you actually test a plugin? I have no app code at all, all functionality comes from the plugins.

I have seen other plugins running their own custom PhpUnit code inline, but shouldn't I be able to fire off Codeception from the root app and it will test available plugins?

Fully aware that this is a vague question, but I can't find any information about specifically testing Craft plugins.

Answer (score 2):

Have you been through Craft's testing documentation? https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/testing/

There's a pretty good walkthrough of the necessary steps there to test plugins: https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/testing/testing-craft/setup.html

Or if you like more real-world examples, Commerce's tests are a good place to start: https://github.com/craftcms/commerce/blob/develop/codeception.yml

From then, you'd trigger all unit tests from the root of your project like:

```
./vendor/bin/codecept run unit
```

Or every test in a single file with:

```
./vendor/bin/codecept run tests/unit/helpers/LocaleHelperTest.php
```

Or a specific test within a single file with:

```
./vendor/bin/codecept run tests/unit/helpers/LocaleHelperTest.php:testEmailGetOrderLanguage
```

Comment: Hi Brad, yes I have been through all the testing documentation that I've found, and like I mentioned I managed to get Codeception running without too many issues.

What I am struggling with is actually getting into the plugin itself, I would expect all the plugin testing code to live inside the plugin, not in the app root? I see your example above and that doesn't look like it has anything to do with a plugin?

Comment: I guess what I'm saying is that I don't understand the full idea about the structure of a root app with active plugins available for testing. I wouldn't expect the plugin to have it's own config settings, those should come from the app, and so on. I haven't found any article that describes this full setup...

Comment: Sorry if I'm not following... do you have a plugin you're building in its own repo similar to https://github.com/craftcms/commerce?

Comment: Yes, exactly. How do I trigger Codeception (from the root app?) to test inside an installed plugin?

Comment: Maybe not exactly... it sounds like you're wanting to test a plugin from a Craft site. i.e. you installed Craft from https://github.com/craftcms/craft, installed a plugin (via whatever means), and want to unit test it from where it lives in the `vendor` folder? Instead of wanting to test the plugin directly from the source of the plugin repo?

Comment: Right, I see what you mean; but I am developing our own plugins locally, not inside the vendor folder, this is what I want to test. Should I just run Codeception in the root of my plugin folder, as if it was the app root?

Comment: "Should I just run Codeception in the root of my plugin folder, as if it was the app root?" Correct - in the Commerce example in my answer (https://github.com/craftcms/commerce/), you'd run it right from the root of the repo using `./vendor/bin/codecept ...`